# Solaris 11.3 - Unable to install system/header

Tags: software-installation, solaris, gcc

I'm (unsuccessfully) trying to get GCC installed on Solaris 11.3 but am running into a lot of issues.
My current issue is that I'm unable to install the package "pkg://solaris/system/header".

Everytime I try to install (pkg install system/header) I get the below error:

```
    root@Sola:~# pkg install -nv system/header 
    Creating Plan (Solver setup): - pkg install: No matching version of system/header can be installed:    
    Reject:  pkg://solaris/system/header@0.5.11-0.151.0.1
                 to
             pkg://solaris/system/header@11.4-11.4.0.0.1.15.0   
    Reason:  This version is excluded by installed incorporation consolidation/osnet/osnet-incorporation@0.5.11-0.175.3.17.0.5.0
```

And this also shows that I definitely don't have any "system/header" packages installed:

```
root@Sola:~# pkg list -fa system/header
NAME (PUBLISHER)                                  VERSION                    IFO
system/header                                     11.4-11.4.0.0.1.15.0       ---
system/header                                     0.5.11-0.175.3.1.0.3.0     ---
system/header                                     0.5.11-0.175.2.0.0.42.2    ---
system/header                                     0.5.11-0.175.1.0.0.24.2    ---
system/header                                     0.5.11-0.175.0.10.1.0.0    ---
system/header                                     0.5.11-0.175.0.0.0.2.1     ---
system/header                                     0.5.11-0.151.0.1           ---
```

Also here's the "pkg entire" file to show the my system version:

```
root@Sola:~# pkg info entire
             Name: entire
          Summary: entire incorporation including Support Repository Update (Oracle Solaris 11.3.17.5.0).
      Description: This package constrains system package versions to the same
                   build.  WARNING: Proper system update and correct package
                   selection depend on the presence of this incorporation.
                   Removing this package will result in an unsupported system.
                   For more information see:
                   https://support.oracle.com/rs?type=doc&id=2045311.1
         Category: Meta Packages/Incorporations
            State: Installed
        Publisher: solaris
          Version: 0.5.11 (Oracle Solaris 11.3.17.5.0)
    Build Release: 5.11
           Branch: 0.175.3.17.0.5.0
   Packaging Date: Fri Feb 17 02:04:57 2017
Last Install Time: Sun Mar 12 07:33:24 2017
             Size: 5.46 kB
             FMRI: pkg://solaris/entire@0.5.11,5.11-0.175.3.17.0.5.0:20170217T020457Z
```

All I need to do is be able to compile some code on this machine.

**EDIT:** 
Thanks for the tip, below is the output from pkg publisher. As mentioned I've been having a lot of trouble trying to install GCC (with similar "incorporation" errors being given), so maybe these issues are related?

```
root@Sola:~# pkg publisher
PUBLISHER                   TYPE     STATUS P LOCATION
solaris                     origin   online F http://pkg.oracle.com/solaris/release/
```

**EDIT 2:** 
Is there any (easy) way to somehow standardize the entire system or bring all basic system packages up/down to a standard level where they are all compatible? I'm not sure why it's so difficult to install what I thought would be basic system packages most distro's are normally shipped with :(

Comment: It looks like your package repository does not have a `system/header` package that matches your installed incorporation.  I am not sure why you have Solaris 11.4 packages show as available for a Solaris 11.3 system, nor why your repository seems to be missing packages.  Post the output of `pkg publisher` to see what repositories you are using.  If you are using local repositories, make sure they are up-to-date with packages that match your installed incorporation.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response, just added the output to my question :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your package repository is pointing to the Solaris 11 release, but the `pkg info entire` output says your incorporation is from the "Support Repository Update."  This would indicate that this system either is or used to be under an Oracle support license.  A system under support would normally use the package repository located at `https://pkg.oracle.com/solaris/support/` instead of the default `http://pkg.oracle.com/solaris/release/`.

If the system is still under a support contract, you should be able to setup the support package repository (requires figuring out entitlements and certificates) and get the newest Support Repository Update and then you should be able to install the packages you want.

If this system used to be under a support contract which is no longer available, then you would not have access to any of the packages that match your incorporation, which seems to be the issue you are asking about.  You would either have to downgrade to the most recent 11.3 release or upgrade to the current 11.4 release.

Comment: Oh wow, didn't even realize that. I'm not sure if it's still under a support contract, but when I try and do "pkg set-publisher https://pkg.oracle.com/solaris/support" I get an error that it's not a valid publisher name, so I assume this might mean there's no longer a support contract...

Also do you know any guides/advice on how to roll-back to a "vanilla" version of Solaris 11.3 (or upgrade to 11.4) with a standard installation (no support license)?
Can't seem to find much information online for doing this without a "support license"

Comment: You would need to figure out entitlements and certificates to make the support repository work, and you have to use `https://`.  [This document](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/servers-storage-admin/o11-018-howto-update-s11-1572261.html) covers how to setup the support repository and check if your system is under contract.  If it is not under a support contract, then you have lost access to any packages that would match your incorporation and would need to switch to one of the available release versions.

Comment: Oracle seems to like making things difficult for people who do not pay, hence no documentation for "no support."  You could try to update your installed incorporation to 11.4 and see what happens (not sure of the necessity of this server, do not do this to a server in production), make sure you have good backups first.

Comment: Haha tell me about it, never had these types of issues with Linux ;).
Thanks heaps for your help. One of my colleagues thinks we do have a support contract for the server (just need to find the login details now :) ). Not sure why the pkg publisher was set to the "release" repo and not the "support" one. Fingers crossed once I set the pkg publisher to "https://pkg.oracle.com/solaris/support/" it will fix these errors.