# OpenIndiana: getting "excluded by installed incorporation" errors trying to install packages on a fresh install of hipster-20211031

Tags: illumos, openindiana, ips

I am trying out OpenIndiana for the first time.  I used the live image `OI-hipster-gui-20211031.iso` (which seems to be the latest version) to install into a qemu-kvm virtual machine.

The very first thing I wanted to do was set up a development environment.  According to [this page from the OpenIndiana documentation](http://docs.openindiana.org/contrib/git/#installing-git), "installing Git on OpenIndiana Hipster is simple."  However, I found it to be not so simple:

```
ppelleti@illumos:~$ sudo pkg install git
Creating Plan (Solver setup): |
pkg install: No matching version of developer/versioning/git can be installed:
  Reject:  pkg://openindiana.org/developer/versioning/git@2.35.1-2022.0.0.0
             to
           pkg://openindiana.org/developer/versioning/git@2.36.1-2022.0.0.0
  Reason:  This version is excluded by installed incorporation consolidation/userland/userland-incorporation@0.5.11-2020.0.1.14595
ppelleti@illumos:~$
```

I tried installing a different package, and got the same error message:

```
ppelleti@illumos:~$ sudo pkg install build-essential
Creating Plan (Solver setup): |
pkg install: No matching version of metapackages/build-essential can be installed:
  Reject:  pkg://openindiana.org/metapackages/build-essential@1.0-2022.0.0.1
  Reason:  This version is excluded by installed incorporation consolidation/userland/userland-incorporation@0.5.11-2020.0.1.14595
ppelleti@illumos:~$
```

I searched the web for "excluded by installed incorporation", and it seems to be a common problem, but it doesn't seem to have a clear solution, especially not one that is applicable to my situation.

For example, [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/486281/solaris-11-3-unable-to-install-system-header) seems to indicate it is a problem with the package publisher.  Here is my package publisher:

```
ppelleti@illumos:~$ pkg publisher
PUBLISHER                   TYPE     STATUS P LOCATION
openindiana.org              origin   online F http://pkg.openindiana.org/hipster/
ppelleti@illumos:~$
```

This isn't something I set up.  This publisher is just what the fresh install of `hipster-20211031` came with, right out of the box.

The question I linked to seemed to involve the publisher being out of date because of a Solaris support contract expiring, but that doesn't seem to be relevant to my situation, because OpenIndiana is open source, so there shouldn't be any licensing issue.

Is there an easy fix for this?  Coming from Linux, I was not expecting this level of difficulty.  `pkg` seems to be far more arcane than `apt-get` is.

Comment: I had the same problem but I found that after a pkg update everything worked again.

Comment: Thanks!  That worked perfectly!  Would you like to write that up as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To echo the above comment, running `pkg update` (which took a long time with 587 packages to update), then rebooting the system resolved this issue for me.

Note that this was a totally fresh OpenIndiana 2022.10 Text Install installation, so even if your system is brand new, as it were, you may need to go through this process first before you're able to install new packages.